# Dokuwiki loses formatting after refreshing

Tags: wiki, dokuwiki

I just finished installing dokuwiki after tons of research. for 5 seconds i was really happy that I finished. However, after i clicked on the dokuwiki logo (which usually takes you to the start page) the wiki lost its format (see picture attached)
why is this happening ? i tried uninstall and install again and the problem happens after 2 minutes of each new installation
[image: BEFORE]

[image: This is AFTER]

the wiki is hosted on IIS server
browser (i tried chrome and edge and firefox ) different pcs

Comment: Does Ctrl+F5 change the situation? Try to press F12 and look on Network panel if there is any difference between normal and failing load. It looks like script /wiki/lib/exe/css.php?t=dokuwiki&tseed=%HASH_HERE% URI can't be accessed or returns an error. Do you experience any problem with page edits?

Comment: Yes ctrl+f5 ( or shift +f5) fix it for the time being, but after you refresh again the problem happens again ( even if you delete the browser cashe )